# How to identify font name for a run in .docx file?

Tags: fonts, docx

I have a run:

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00A7650B">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b/>
                    <w:sz w:val="40"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="40"/>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>This is a title</w:t>
            </w:r>
```

Default paragraph style is:

```
<w:style w:type="paragraph" w:default="1" w:styleId="Normal">
    <w:name w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:qFormat/>
</w:style>
```

This run appears with Calibri font name in msword. The only place where Calibri is present inside .docx is theme1.xml (a:theme/a:themeElements/a:fontScheme/a:minorFont/a:latin). It is theme "Office Theme" with fontScheme "Office".

1. Is this a right place to search for the font name in this case?
2. How can I identify this in code, that for this run I should use theme1.xml and theme name is 'Office Theme'? Please don't suggest to use OpenXML SDK, I have to do it myself.

Comment: If the font is not explicitly named in your document, Word will use whatever is default for "Normal" on the system your *user* is using. You can't tell from the document alone.

Comment: This is wrong. Different .docx have different fonts and are not platform-dependent.

Comment: It depends on the Normal template (which also holds the definitions for the used Theme). I'm sure "Normal" can be redefined, but usually that should leave some evidence in the .docx file. But if that's not there you can only assume it's a normal Normal template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Content_types].xml there is reference to theme1.xml:

```
 <Override 
  PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" 
  ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/>
```

Inside theme1.xml there is

```
        <a:minorFont>
            <a:latin typeface="Calibri"/>
```

its default font for regular text.

Comment: I have gone through your [blog](https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx), it's very helpful.  please correct my understanding, can I consider that minor font relates to non-heading text and major font relates to headings always?

Comment: Sorry @Satyaaditya I am not in this business now. The only way you can find out is by performing experiments.